# How to overload operator< for putting objects into set

Tags: c++, set, operators, operator-overloading

I want to put objects into set and as I know, I need to overload operator< for that. So I came up with something like this:

```
   bool Client::operator< (Category &cC1, Category &cC2){
      return cC1.getName() < cC2.getName();
   }

   // Setters----------------------------------------------------------------
   void Client::addNewCategory(const string &categName){
      Category cat(categName);
      i->categoriesMap.insert(i->categoriesMapPos++, cat);
   }
```

i is a pointer to inner class where set categoriesMap and its iterator is defined.

So I overloaded operator<, but it still doesn't work, i get an error that operator has too many parameters (but how can I compare objects without having two of them)? Also, I get an error `5   IntelliSense: class "ExpenseManagerNamespace::Client" has no member "operator<"` I use visual studio 2013.

Comment: @remyabel: If it's comparing objects of the type it's a member of. This is comparing a different type, so shouldn't be a member at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the operator a free (non-member) function:

```
bool operator< (Category const& cC1, Category const& cC2){
   return cC1.getName() < cC2.getName();
}
```

You may have to give friendship to that function if `getName` is not public.

The member function version of `operator<` is used to compare some other object against `this`. That is probably not what you want here, since `this` is of type `Client` in your case and you seem to want to compare two `Category`s.

Comment: Yes I need to compare Category objects, not Client objects. So, what I need to do is to make it a non-member function. But If I do that, how to compare two category objects. I am lost a little bit...

Comment: @Fractal What is the problem that you run into when implementing the comparison operator as a free function? I see that you are a bit confused by this, but it's hard for me to tell why.

Comment: Then I get another error `"Error 1 error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const ExpenseManagerNamespace::Category' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Comment: @Fractal Sorry, I missed that you were missing `const`s on the parameters. Edited the answer accordingly. Note that now `getName` also needs to be a `const` member function for the code to compile.